# Cannot scroll vertically

Tags: css

I have this page:

http://projects.kleelof.com/rr_chat_roulette/

It is a very simple page, but, for some reason, when the page is too tall, the vertical scroll bars do not come on.

Could someone take a quick look and tell me what I am doing wrong?

I will post the CSS and related HTML below:

CSS:

```
    body
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#main_area
{
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.bottom_text
{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="main_area">
        <center>
            <img src="images/header.png"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <div id="altContent" style="width:900px; background-color:#000000;">
                <h1>rickrose_chat_roulette</h1>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <span class="bottom_text" style="font-size: 24px;">Chatroulette & 

Omegle Alternative for Hot Good Looking People</span>
                <br/><br/>
                <span class="bottom_text" style="font-size: 14px;">

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span> 
        </center>

    </div>
```

take care,
lee

Comment: It's for problems like this, where jsFiddle is needed lol

Comment: btevfik - yes, there is not no accounting for taste. I am at the mercy of my clients. vletech - I am not familiar with jsFiddle, how could it help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, on line 31 in your main CSS file you have `html,body{overflow:hidden)` If you change this to `auto` then that will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing it. The CSS file only has 19 lines and there is no assignment to the overflow in the entire CSS.

Comment: NEvermind. I totally missed that bit of CSS in the main HTML.

Comment: Sorry yes it's the main page not the css file.